# SSIS load to CSV puts everything in Column A

Tags: sql, csv, ssis, etl

I have seen multiple topics about related issues, but no solution yet.

I am using SSIS to load data from a query into a CSV file. When I configure the package and click preview, everything looks fine, but when opening the CSV file, the four separate values are in one column and not in 4 separate columns with headers.

This is my preview in the Flat File destination (which looks fine):
[preview destination][image: 1]

This is the configuration of the flat file connection:
[configuration flat file connection][image: 2]

This is the preview from the connection manager:
[connection manager][image: 3]

But this is how the results looks like:

[result all in 1 column][image: 4]

Is there anyone who knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance. Best regards, Mike

Comment: your last screenshot shows data are correctly saved, It's just your excel doesn't open it up correctly , try to open your csv file with notepad++ and see if there is any abnormality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open CSV using excel, use `;` for value/column delimiter instead of `,` for separate value in each column.

And yes, CSV stands for Comma Separated Value, but excel read it as a single value.

I had same issues yesterday...

Comment: It looks like this is the solution, many thanks.

Comment: @mcrv91 I know its solution because I had problem for a few days.