# Flat file connection manager exports all values into column A (CSV file)

Tags: file, ssis, delimiter, flat

When using a flat file connection in a SSIS package in VS, all the different values go into column A, instead of being separated into different columns. The preview in the flat file manager dialogue box looks OK. I read a suggestion to use ; as a column delimiter, and open the CSV file created using excel, but that did not do the job. Any suggestions please?

To get a CSV file exported with  each value in its own column and not all values in column A separated by the delimiter.

Comment: The referenced suggestion is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67706414/ssis-load-to-csv-puts-everything-in-column-a/76384707#76384707

Comment: As everyone has already said. SSIS did its job to create the delimited file. Your version of Excel needs to be configured to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Excel to convert the text to columns because you used ; and not comma (Excel does comma automatically.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5xOf.png]

Then

[image]

Then select semicolin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, there is no problem.

You are creating a Delimited Flat File and you chose the delimiter of a semicolon. If you open the resulting output file with a text editor (Notepad) you'll see data like

```
Col1;Col2;Col3
ABCD;DEFG;HIJK
LMNO;PQRS;TUVW
```

If the data looks like that, then you have successfully created a delimited file.

The "problem" comes from Excel making assumptions about the data. Excel sees a file with .CSV, Comma Separated Values, extension and as part of reading that data in, splits it into columns based on the comma character and finding none, it presents the data as you see it in one column.

If you change the file extension to .txt, Excel walks you through a brief wizard to understand how it should interpret the data.

[image]

Here I unchecked the previous value and select semicolon
[image]

Here you can see Excel understands the columns and I have what I expected to see.
[image]

The challenge around using a different file extension is the user needs to either Right Click on the file and choose Open with Excel or Open Excel and then Open a file, change the default filter from All Excel Files to All Files or Text Files and then pick the correct option.

Or, you change your SSIS package to use the comma delimiter, leave the extension as .csv and Excel will correctly interpret the data when it loads.

If you have embedded data, like an Address of "100 Main St, Kansas City, MO" you'd need to modify your Flat File Connection Manager to indicate how you'd like to handle embedded delimiters. Otherwise, you'd end up with something like

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Address
ABCD,DEFG,HIJK,100 Main St,Kansas City,MO
LMNO,PQRS,TUVW,Antartica
```

That'd result in 6 columns on row 2 instead of the intended 4.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. So maybe I can rephrase - how can I export my data in the SSIS package to an excel file where the columns are actually in different cells and not delimited?

Comment: Help me understand what "columns are actually in different cells and not delimited?" means. Click the Edit button on your question and see if you can describe the starting point and the end result. Feel free to mock up screenshots or whatever you need